# How can I make a put request with okhttp3 without multipart body

Tags: java, servlets, okhttp

My web service, which is a java servlet, accepts a put request with url params to take a specific action. The code below gets what I want done, but I would love to know if there is a better way to make a put request without adding a multipart body.

Do all put requests in Java Servlets expect a multipart body?

Do all put requests made using okhttp3 expect a multipart body?

Am I misunderstanding something else?

```
    body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("", "") // I would love to eliminate this.
                .build();

    request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url + "?my_param=" + URLEncoder.encode(myParam, "utf-8"))
                .put(body)
                .build();

    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

From a pragmatic point of view, I'd say that you're looking at an implementation restriction of Servlets and/or OkHttp and it can probably be made to work using different libraries.

However,

from a standards view, I think your approach is incorrect and you should use a POST instead of a PUT. This requires reading both [RFC-2616 (HTTP/1.1)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), section 9.6 on the POST request, and [RFC-1630 (URL's in WWW)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1630.txt), the section on query strings.

From the HTTP spec, section 9.6:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations. In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.

From the URL's spec, page 6:

> QUERY STRINGS
>
> The question mark ("?", ASCII 3F hex) is used to delimit the boundary between the URI of a queryable object, and a set of words used to express a query on that object.  When this form is used, the combined URI stands for the object which results from the query being applied to the original object.

These two combine to imply that you cannot use a PUT request in the way that you're trying to.

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I get this, a put request is generally not intended to be used with query params as is a post? Hence the implementation of the put request in okhttp3 with a requirement for a request body intended for the "enclosed entity"?

Comment: The key thing is that PUT tells the server "put <this request body> at <this exact uri>". whereas POST tells the server "handle <this request body> for me in whatever way you see fit".